# Urn probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains 3 white balls and 5 black balls. You randomly choose 3 balls. If 2 are white
and one is black, you stop. If not, you replace the balls in the urn and again randomly select 3 balls

What is the probability that you make exactly 20 selections?

Comment: Here, does '*You randomly choose 3 balls*' mean with or without replacement? The answers given at the time of this comment assume no replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$A_i:\text{"We have 2 white balls and 1 black ball at the i-th selection"}.$$

You win at the $i^{th}$ selection with probability of $$p(A_i)=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}$$

and failed at the $i^{th}$ selection with the probability of
$$p(A_i^c)=1-\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}.$$

Moreover, to do exactly 20 selections, you have to failed the 19 first selections and win at the $20^{th}$ selection, and thus, if we denote the event

$$B:\text{"We do exactly 20 selections"},$$
you get that 
$$B=A_1^c\cap...\cap A_{19}^c\cap A_{20}.$$

Since all the $A_i$ and $A_i^c$ are independent, you finally conclude that

$$p(B)=p(A_1^c\cap...\cap A_{19}\cap A_{20})=P(A_1^c)\cdot ...\cdot p(A_{19}^c)\cdot p(A_{20}),$$
therefore
$$p(B)=\left(1-\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}\right)^{19}\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}=...$$

Comment: This is a beautiful answer but maybe you could add some more explanation. Like note your usage of multiplying probabilities and maybe reference some theory.

Comment: @Nick: thanks, I completed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the probability of picking two white and one black ball.  We can do this three ways WWB, WBW and BWW and the probability of doing this is:

$$\dfrac{3}{8} \cdot \dfrac{2}{7} \cdot \dfrac{5}{6} + \dfrac{3}{8} \cdot \dfrac{5}{7} \cdot \dfrac{2}{6} + \dfrac{5}{8} \cdot \dfrac{3}{7} \cdot \dfrac{2}{6} = \dfrac{15}{56}$$

The probability of not pricking two whites and a black is therefore $1 - \dfrac{15}{56} = \dfrac{41}{56}$

Making the probability of needing exactly 20 draws.

$$\left( \dfrac{41}{56} \right)^{19} \cdot \dfrac{15}{56} \approx 5.551 \times 10^{-24}$$